# Display duplicate characters in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I wrote some code in C++ to display duplicate characters in a string, but if a character is repeated more than three times, the code prints the repeated character more than once.

For example if the string is `aaaddbss`, it should only print out `ads` but it prints `aaads` instead.

What am I doing wrong?

```
cout << " Please enter a string" << endl;

cin.getline(input, 100); //  example input (ahmad wahidy) the output reads a a h a d instead of a h d 

for (int i = 0;input[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1;input[j]!='\0'; j++)
    {
        if (input[i] == input[j])
        {
            cout << input[i] << " ";
        }
    }

}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Presumably this is C++? This is missing definitions for things like `input`. Please make it a complete example. I have a feeling `input` is not `std::string`, which it should be since using raw character buffers is a bad plan.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line. Then it will be very obvious what the problem is.

Comment: @tadman `input` can't be `std::string`, since it wouldn't compile if it were. `cin` doesn't have an overload of `getline` method which accepts `std::string`.

Comment: Use a debugger - or better - use paper and two pencils to simulate what the program does. It should be clear then that you've chosen a wrong approach. If it is C++, an easy approach could be to use a map.

Comment: @StephanLechner Wouldn't a `std::set` be better?

Comment: @Some programmer dude: right, when not counting occurrences but just checking for duplicates.

Comment: @StephanLechner our instructor doesn't want us to use map, thanks anyways

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the reference, I will check it out

Comment: @tadman yes its c++

Comment: What is supposed to happen with a string like "ABCABC" - is `A` required to be printed once or twice?    Also, are the characters required to be output in order of their first appearance, or some other order?

Comment: @Peter yes A is supposed to be printed once, thanks

Comment: @StephanLechner i checked your code, thank you so much. that's the method i was looking for! thank you again

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using your own custom methods, why not use a short and standard method?

Given an `std::string input` with the text, this will print the unique chars:

```
std::set<char> unique(input.begin(), input.end());
for (auto & c : unique)
{
    std::cout << c << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::count` and `std::set`:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "hellohowareyou";
    set<char>the_set(s.begin(), s.end());
    for (char i:the_set)
        if (count(s.begin(), s.end(), i) > 1)
            cout << i << endl;


}
```

Output:

```
e
h
l
o
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use a `map` (and probably also not allowed to use a `set`), you could simply use an array of integers to count occurrences, with one entry for each possible char value. Note that a character - when taken as an ASCII value - can be directly used as an index for an array; however, to avoid negative indices, each character value should first be converted to an unsigned value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    const char* input = "aaaddbss";
    int occurrences[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0;input[i] !='\0'; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = input[i];
        if (occurrences[c]==0) {
            occurrences[c]++;
        }
        else if (occurrences[c]==1) {
            occurrences[c]++;
            cout << "duplicate: " << c << endl;
        }
    }cout << endl;
}
```